# Different behaviour and styling for Safari

Tags: css, reactjs, font-awesome, gatsby

I'm working on Gatsby application, I added Font Awesome Icon and styling, but the appearance is different for Safari. Icon completely lost shape and proportions.

## Safari

[image: Safari]

## Google Chrome

[image: Google Chrome]

## React

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faDatabase } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

<span className="awesome-parent">
  <FontAwesomeIcon 
    className="major db-style awesome-icon" 
    icon={faDatabase}
  />
</span>
```

## Styling

```
.awesome-parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-color: lightgray;


  .awesome-icon {
    border: solid 1px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
    padding: 2em;
  }

  .db-style {
    color: _palette(db-blue);
    border-color: lightgray;
  }
```

}

Can anyone spot what did I wrong? I would like to add that I have a few other icons with exactly the same styling, but different colour and they behave like expected.

I still haven't figured it out so I'm adding here deployed website to whom may it debug.

https://bartoszszymanski.net

Regards

Comment: `color: _palette(db-blue);` isn't valid CSS syntax, so the line would be ignored when rendered. Also, don't break strings over several lines, this could cause issues as well (className).

Comment: @BillieBobbel I use `.scss`, so `_pallette` works as expected. What about breaking string over several lines, that's how it's styled here because the line was broken weird. I'll rever it.

Answer (score 0):

Please change `border-radius: 100%;` to pixel value. Try `border-radius: 25px;` i hope it'll help you. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't change anything.

Comment: Have you deployed your code on any server or any work example? For more clarifications. Thanks